# Getting multiple notification on device

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I am implementing the Push Notification using below code. Its working fine but its displaying multiple notification in status bar on device. How I can merge the multiple Notification into single status Bar. Please suggest.

```
 //code//
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.media.RingtoneManager;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

 public class FirebasePluginMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebasePlugin";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background

    String title;
    String text;
    String id;
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        id = remoteMessage.getMessageId();
    } else {
        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        text = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
        id = remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(id)){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
        id = Integer.toString(n);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message id: " + id);
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Title: " + title);
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body/Text: " + text);

    // TODO: Add option to developer to configure if show notification when app on foreground
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(title) || (!remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())) {
        boolean showNotification = (FirebasePlugin.inBackground() || !FirebasePlugin.hasNotificationsCallback()) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(title));
        sendNotification(id, title, text, remoteMessage.getData(), showNotification);
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String id, String title, String messageBody, Map<String, String> data, boolean showNotification) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 int numMessages = 0;
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        bundle.putString(key, data.get(key));
    }
    if (showNotification) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnNotificationOpenReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText("New message")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);




         int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("notification_icon", "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (resID != 0) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(resID);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    } else {
        bundle.putBoolean("tap", false);
        FirebasePlugin.sendNotification(bundle);
    }
}


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to merge multiple notifications. You can use summarizing or bundling to collapse the notifications.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
is a good resource to use.

**Summarizing**:
This is accomplished by creating a notification with a given ID so that you can update it at a later time when another notification is received

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
...
```

EX:

[image]

**Bundling**:

This can be accomplished by using the Builder.setGroup() functionality.

[image]

Take a look at the android notifications design patterns documentation for more information on notification guidelines.
https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior

Comment: Dear David, We are stuck at stacking push notification. can you please check and let us know if you can help   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852467/cannot-find-symbol-in-push-notification-error-notificationbuilder-setcontenttex